# What causes the noise when you get an electric shock?

Tags: electricity, acoustics, lightning

When we get a minor static electric shock, we often hear a noise associated with the shock.

Or for example, when you swat a fly with a zapper, you can hear a noise from the electric transfer.

What causes this noise?

Comment: The same thing that causes thunder, but on a smaller scale. see; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunder

Comment: I guess these are two things: the outside noise that everyone else can here, and the "virtual" noise induced in some nerves that only you can "hear". I remember a a child licking my tong against an battery and "seeing" some light.

Comment: That noise is the sound of you screaming!

Comment: @GyroGearloose, perhaps you have a touch of _[synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia)_. Not everybody who licks a 9V battery sees light. (Don't ask me how I know!)

Answer (score 3):

The transfer of charge ionizes the air around it, making that zap sound.

Comment: But if you are touching the object, then the charge flows directly through you, no? How does it ionise the air if it doesn’t pass through the air?

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove around the moment you (dis)connect the source of charge to(from) the object to which the charge would flow, there's a tiny distance between them. The electric field strength, which is inversely proportional to distance, grows very high, which does break down the air gap. Then the [instability of the contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_bounce) makes this breakdown happen many times in small time period, leading to the buzz.